NGINX SSL PRIVATE KEY routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line error:140B0009:SSL
Hello guyz I am trying to renew my ssl certificate in nginx. I did same way earlier and it worked but this time after create bundle.crt and private.key file when I try to restart nginx I am getting this error

nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/srv/www/website.yaabi.com/calletest/20242.yaabi.com.key") failed (SSL: error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)

Though my certificate and key are matching and private key format is also exact same
private key
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
//key
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
AFTER properly checking I was able may be the issue was related to copy paste but now facing this issue.
Error Screenshot
I was expecting to work new SSL certificate properly

There is likely something corrupt in the file - only one can not be more specific w/o actually having the file. Common errors: wrong line ends (like CRLF instead of LF), missing characters from cut+paste into a file, wrong encoding (like UTF-16 instead of ASCII/UTF-8), ... Typically these errors happen if the key is somehow created by copy+pasting.

@SteffenUllrich encoding is UTF 8 and I created new file and pasted the content there but still same issue and I tested the same copied content there wasn't any issue. Is there anyway I can share the file with you ?

Please show the first and last 32 bytes of the file as hex, for example by using xxd. This does not reveal any secrets but will show any unexpected new lines, missing characters etc. But make sure to really use the actual file as input, i.e. not copy+paste into some other program

@SteffenUllrich thank u so much by carefully copy paste I was able to solve the issue but now facing other issue I added screenshot in the question please check if u can help thank U again

This is a totally different question and the reason might be a misconfiguration of the server, i.e. duplicate definitions for listening on the same IP:port. But impossible to point out the exact place w/o having the complete configuration. Anyway, this is better asked at serverfault.com.

Thanks to @SteffenUllrich. I was able to resolve by properly copying and pasting without extra lines.

There is likely something corrupt in the file - only one can not be
more specific w/o actually having the file. Common errors: wrong line
ends (like CRLF instead of LF), missing characters from cut+paste into
a file, wrong encoding (like UTF-16 instead of ASCII/UTF-8), ...
Typically these errors happen if the key is somehow created by
copy+pasting. –

